# Reference request: sheaf cohomology after Bott & Tu

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Undergrad here. I want to understand sheaf cohomology. (Not sure if this is relevant, but I also want to understand Étale cohomology.)

To do this, I've been studying de Rham cohomology from Bott and Tu, to lead into Cech cohomology, which I think is one potential route to general sheaf cohomology(?) It looks like B&T covers this briefly. I'll be trying to hit the following sections:

- Section 10, presheaves and Cech cohomology
- Section 13, monodromy

But past that, it looks like I'll need to find other sources for studying sheaf cohomology. **So, my questions:**

1. For my purposes, are there other sections (past section 6) of B&T I ought to read?
2. What is a good 'next read' for understanding sheaf cohomology?
3. Is it advisable to study sheaf cohomology before etale, or are the two more or less independent?

Comment: I can't speak as much to the topological side of things, but I think having a strong background in scheme theory (and Galois theory for some intuition) is pretty crucial for being able to get into etale cohomology. That being said, you can get around a lot of stuff if you're comfortable with category theory and Grothendieck topologies.

Comment: I’m not too sure about what you’ve seen, but there’s a rather radical shift in abstraction from de Rham or Cech cohomology into sheaf or étale cohomology. The latter two do not come from explicit complexes, so they are harder to manipulate. So either way, you will need a good understanding of sheaf theory and some familiarity with homological algebra – so sheaf cohomology could be “training”. Also, Geoff is right that étale cohomology requires good knowledge of schemes.